# Blackberry Install background service from UI application?

Tags: blackberry, native, background-service

Hi i need to create an uninstallable background service that would run from application, **if the user is registered** otherwise wait until it will receive my condition to get installed?

1 ) how to create an uninstallable background service?

2 ) how to install it by user registered condition?

I would really appreciate the help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that any, even system .cod file, can be uninstalled via javaloader.exe utility that comes with JDE distribution package. Or via any application that utilizes relevant RIM SDK API calls. So there is no way to make a **real** uninstallable package.

It is possible to create a new cod file on the device using API calls.

Take a look at [CodeModuleManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.1api/index.html) class. It is possible to download the service cod file to byte array and invoke
[CreateNewModule](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.1api/net/rim/device/api/system/CodeModuleManager.html#createNewModule%28int,%20byte%5b%5d,%20int%29) method to make new cod file based on this byte array.

Comment: ok thank you very much, i will take a look at this and i promise you to write about it.

One more question how do i block navigation url in BlackBerry internet browser?

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, do you want to have a browser functionality but do not want to have "Open url" via menu functionality available. If so, then take a look at [BrowserField class](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/BrowserField.html)

Comment: If you want to keep a service on the device, regardless of user action, and restrict browsing to particular web sites, the functionality you're looking for is in the BES. This kind of think would be very difficult to implement via the published API.

Comment: Thank you i will check on that.